# Find Next Pattern after a constant found

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list of words and wanted to know the position or index of the next word which follow some pattern (this is the simple example but regular expression is sort of neccessary devil)

```
list = ["A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","-","C","D"]
```

Now I have found the position of "A"

```
a = [i for i,x in enumerate(list) if x == "A"]
```

However if I want to find "C" everytime "A" is found and then recursively start again with next "A".

Answer (score 1):

`list.index` has an optional argument `start`, you can use that to specify the starting index.

```
>>> lis = ["A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","-","C","D"]
>>> for i,x in enumerate(lis):
...     if x == 'A':
...         print "next 'C' found at",lis.index('C',i)
...         
next 'C' found at 2
next 'C' found at 6
next 'C' found at 11
```

**Update:**

```
>>> import re
>>> strs =  "".join(lis)
>>> strs
'ABCDABCDAB-CD'
>>> r = re.compile(r'A[^C]+C')
>>> [m.end()-1 for m in r.finditer(strs)]
[2, 6, 11]
#or
>>> r = re.compile(r'A[^C]+')
>>> [m.end() for m in r.finditer(strs)]
[2, 6, 11]
```

Comment: That was blazingly fast @Ashwini ... Thanks a bunch.

Comment: However I am trying to find a way in which reg. can be used. It's minimal example and not true case.

Comment: @LonelySoul you need a string for that, regexp doesn't work on lists. See my updated solution.